# changes are not updated in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse. I am trying eclipse with a simple web application. Whenever I make  changes in the jsp pages and run the application. The changes are not updated in the server. please let me know the problem.

Comment: Are you developing for Google App Engine?

Comment: things like version, whether using WTP, dynamic or static web project, server name and version, server config, etc are also important...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are making changes in jsp pages and if you save it then immediately changes are getting updated but if you written any servlet and you made change in it then that might be not updating immediately.Because might be in your eclipse auto build option is not enable. So to enable it click on project- there is check box for auto build just mark it and now your application will build automatically so it will show updation on server side.