# Eclipse not updating build (even with auto-build and cleaning project)

Tags: eclipse, build, compilation

I know this has been asked a few times ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712793/eclipse-not-updating-android-project), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434489/why-is-my-code-not-updating-on-my-app-after-updated-eclipse), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980599/changes-are-not-updated-in-eclipse)) but the suggestion given in those questions is to clean project or check auto-build is enabled.
The thing is, I did all of that and I still don't get Eclipse to update my build.
I downloaded the latest Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Kepler, release 2) a week ago and I don't have the android SDK installed (the only "add-on" I installed to Eclipse is Tomcat 7).

Just to test this, I created a new java project with only this code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(10/5);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get "2" printed on console. But then I change 10/5 to 2/5, clean the project and run it again. Still printing "2".

I uncheck the auto-build option and then manually go to Project > Build Project, then run it again. Still printing "2".

Then I refresh (F5) the project just in case, and run it again. Still printing "2".

Refresh (F5) again, build project manually, run. Still printing "2".

What is wrong with Eclipse???

It does this with all my projects, not just this one (which is a very small project I created to test this behavior).

Any hints on what I can do? Thanks.